Set background color of canvas with html2canvas
I'm using html2canvas to take screenshots from elements in a page
html2canvas(element).then(canvas => canvas.toDataURL());

Works find, but the only thing that goes wrong is that the background color of the page is ignored. Is there a way to fix this in html2canvas or to define a background color?

Does this answer your question? How to make transparent color white instead of black in html2canvas?

No it seems not. They suggest using _html2canvas which does not seem to exist

The newer answers on that question might be what you are looking for. You can pass the background color as part of the options of html2canvas.

Ah, you're right. Its the other part of the accepted answer. html2canvas accepts a second argument in which you can define a backkgroundColor

You can add the background color to element before snapshot and undo it after canvas generation.


const element = document.getElementById('your-element-id');

// Set background color of the element
element.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';  // Replace with your desired background color

// Use html2canvas to capture the element
html2canvas(element).then(canvas => {
    // Reset background color of the element after capturing
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';  // Reset to default or any other background style

    // Now you can use the canvas
    const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(dataURL);
});



